# iconTint в меню на ToolBar в Android

Tags: android, android-studio, menu, android-toolbar

У меня есть меню:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_search"
            android:icon="@drawable/search"
            android:iconTint="@color/iconBackground"
            app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_info_bar"
            android:icon="@drawable/search_barcod"
            android:iconTint="@color/iconBackground"
            app:showAsAction="always" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_filter_list"
            android:icon="@drawable/select_auction"
            android:iconTint="@color/iconBackground"
            app:showAsAction="always" />

    </menu>
```

которое добавлено в `ToolBar`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main_top"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/logo"
        app:navigationIconTint="@color/iconBackground"
        app:title="@string/app_name" />
```

Цвета **iconBackground** заданы разными для **светлой** и **тёмной** темы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для **тёмной** темы

```
<color name="iconBackground">#292929</color>
```

Для **светлой** темы

```
<color name="iconBackground">#FFFFFF</color>
```

Но почему-то цвет иконок в меню на `Toolbar` получается всегда белым, при этом **navigationIcon** меняет свой цвет.
В чём может быть причина?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом у **xml** меню все в порядке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Каким образом *Цвета iconBackground заданы разными для светлой и темной темы*?

Comment: Обновил сообщение

Comment: Что-то я не наблюдаю атрибута `iconTint` в доках меню. Похоже это нужно задавать программно или в самих иконках

Comment: Не совсем понял почему нет, в файле xml меню у каждой иконки есть iconTint. И где задавать програмно или в самих иконках?

Comment: Обновил сообщение. При просмотре файла меню в Android studio видно что цвета корректно меняются в зависимости от темы. А вот в ToolBar почемуто нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз никто ничего не предложил, то сделал проще. Перевел все иконки в векторный формат **Vector asset (xml)** и назначил цвет **iconBackground** в самом файле **XML**

Comment: Я также делал в своем проекте, вообще в идеале делать так. И иконки будут красивее и адаптивнее.